# Understanding namespace using directive

Tags: c++, namespaces

In the following program we have two namespaces:

```
#include <iostream>
namespace B
{
    int c = 42;
}

namespace A
{
    using namespace B;
    int a = 442;
}

namespace B
{
    int b = 24;
}

int main()
{ 
    std::cout << A::a << std::endl; //442
    std::cout << A::b << std::endl; //24
    std::cout << A::c << std::endl; //42
}
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/925f39473ff26382)**

I thought the behavior of the program is being covered by `N4296::3.3.6/1 [basic.scope.namespace]`:

> A namespace member name has namespace scope. Its potential scope
>   includes its namespace from the name’s point of declaration (3.3.2)
>   onwards; and *for each using-directive* (7.3.4) that nominates the
>   member’s namespace, the member’s potential scope includes that portion
>   of the potential scope of the using-directive *that follows the*
>   *member’s point of declaration*.

So, in the case of the `namespace A`, the potential scope of the member `b` shouldn't have included any portion of the program, because the member was declared later then the `using directive`. But actually it can be found by qualified name lookup. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read this fragment again:

> the member’s [`b`'s] potential scope includes that portion of the potential scope of the using-directive [in `A`] that follows the member’s point of declaration.

I believe you have to read it as stating that `b` is in the scope of `A` from the point of `b`'s declaration onward. Where you print `A::b`, that does in fact "follow the member's point of declaration", so for that line, `b` can be found in the scope of `A`. This is perfectly valid.

Comment: Yes, I'd also say that it's an qualified-name-lookup issue. Covered by 3.4.3.2